# JAX-RS Apache CXF vs Jersey implementations. Encoding

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, cxf

Just wondering if such a code shouldn't return the same using different implementation of JAX-RS? I'm not really into Java.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation.Builder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;

public class RestClientServiceImpl {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String url = "https://foo.bar/test/api/users?q=key:value";
    ClientBuilder builder = ClientBuilder.newBuilder();
    Client client = builder.build();

    System.out.println(String.format("Before doing WebTarget %s ", url));
    WebTarget target = client.target(url);
    System.out.println(String.format("After doing WebTarget  %s ", target.getUri()));
  }
}
```

https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey/download.html
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jersey/bundles/jaxrs-ri/2.40/jaxrs-ri-2.40.zip

```
$ libs="jaxrs-ri/api/*:jaxrs-ri/ext/*:jaxrs-ri/lib/*" ; javac -cp .:${libs} RestClientServiceImpl.java ; java -cp .:${libs} RestClientServiceImpl
Before doing WebTarget https://foo.bar/test/api/users?q=key:value
After doing WebTarget  https://foo.bar/test/api/users?q=key:value
```

https://cxf.apache.org/download.html
https://dlcdn.apache.org/cxf/3.6.2/apache-cxf-3.6.2.zip

```
$ libs="apache-cxf-3.6.2/lib/*" ; javac -cp .:${libs} RestClientServiceImpl.java ; java -cp .:${libs} RestClientServiceImpl
Before doing WebTarget https://foo.bar/test/api/users?q=key:value
After doing WebTarget  https://foo.bar/test/api/users?q=key%3Avalue
```

The difference is encoded colon.

Answer (score 1):

Use UriBuilder instead as various implementation treats this differently. We had very same problem in the past too

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;

public class RestClientServiceImpl {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String url = "https://foo.bar/test/api/users?q=key:value";
    UriBuilder uri = UriBuilder.fromUri(url);
    ClientBuilder builder = ClientBuilder.newBuilder();
    Client client = builder.build();

    System.out.println(String.format("Before doing WebTarget %s ", url));
    WebTarget target = client.target(uri.build());
    System.out.println(String.format("After doing WebTarget  %s ", target.getUri()));
  }
}
```